# C# Windows Form - Window Always Focused

Tags: c#

I have a form from which I can open another form. I would like to prevent the user from switching to other forms when form 2 is opened. Thus, the user can only switch to other forms when this windows is closed.

Any help to do so?

Comment: Show your code please!

Comment: You mean to prevent switching to other forms *of your own application*, not to prevent the user to switch to, say, notepad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ShowDialog` method which open a new form in Modal state

```
Form2 frmNew = new Form2();
frmNew.ShowDialog()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a (Modal) Dialog instead of a Window.

A dialog can only be exited by pressing a Cancel/OK button (or Escape key), while windows have normally a Close button.

Example to show a dialog:

```
// C#
//Display frmAbout as a modal dialog
Form frmAbout = new Form();
frmAbout.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 0):

`form.ShowDialog()` instead of `form.Show()`